# How to check if a mongodb document has been modified after reading but before writing to it?

Tags: mongodb

Consider the use case where I am embedding `Address` document IDs into a `User` document. Threads `1` and `2` run at the same time followed by the `Check results` thread.

User:

```
addresses: [1, 2, 3]
```

Async Thread 1:

```
user = userCollection.find(userId)
user.addresses.push(4)
userCollection.update(user)
```

Async Thread 2:

```
user = userCollection.find(userId)
user.addresses.push(5)
userCollection.update(user)
```

Check results:

```
user = userCollection.find(userId)
user.addresses.includes(4) // result is non-deterministic
user.addresses.includes(5) // result is non-deterministic
```

Do I need to implement my own document level locks at the application level to prevent multi-threaded applications from overwriting data that other threads are currently writing?

Maybe I'm missing a built-in atomic function to append to an array? But what about the case of find / replace? I don't just want to 'push' a new value into the array but find an old ID that's been deleted and then remove it. And at the same time another thread wants to add to the array. I'm honestly not sure what the simplest solution is. I've written the problem in psuedo-javascript however I'm using golang for the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [official doc](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/),

> In MongoDB, a write operation is atomic on the level of a single document, even if the operation modifies multiple embedded documents within a single document.

You won't need to care a lot about atomicity for a single document. For your given example, you can simply do an update with an aggregate pipeline, which is available for MongoDB v4.2+.

```js
db.collection.update({
  "userId": 1
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "addresses": {
        "$setUnion": [
          {
            "$filter": {
              "input": "$addresses",
              "as": "a",
              "cond": {
                $ne: [
                  "$$a",
                  3    // element you want to remove
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          // element you want to add
          [
            4
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HdxWhRY9Ryw) for your reference.

If you need to deal with multi-document atomicity, you can opt for [transactions](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/transactions/), which is available for MongoDB v4.0+

Comment: This is interesting thank you. I still think there's a potential for data loss if two separate threads read a value at point A and then both try to write points B and C. Lets say for instance that a doc.val = 1 and threads B and C both try to increment it. Both read the value as 1 and both try to write the new value as 2 when the real value should be 3. Atomicity won't solve this issue - it will merely prevent them writing at the same time. At least to my understanding of the issue currently. Even transactions won't help if two competing transactions read the original document at the value 1.

Comment: Is [retryable reads](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.2/core/retryable-reads/) and [retryable writes](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.2/core/retryable-writes/) what you are looking for?

Comment: In DynamoDB it's called a 'Conditional Put' and it validates the value if the value that you're about to update as you update it. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html#Expressions.ConditionExpressions.PreventingOverwrites

Comment: Okay googling the dynamodb documentation inspired me to google for "mongodb conditional update" which lead me to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69113431/mongodb-update-document-field-with-a-condition and I believe this is exactly what I need

Comment: @fIwJlxSzApHEZIl The principle is actually the same. We are both doing conditional update with aggregate pipeline to handle the update. The difference is your given link is updating a string field and we are updating array field. You can see the condition is set in the `$filter` clause. HTH.

Comment: okay seeing that now. thanks for the help!